# IOS Chorme keyboard overlaps input on focus

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, google-chrome

I've got a responsive page which contains a form with some inputs. The problem is that when I tap one field (when it's focused), the keyboard appears over the input and the rest of screen visible it's not scrollable. This happens only on IOS + Chrome. I'd like the rest of visible screen to be scrollable, can someone help me with this ?

Comment: I am using Backbone.js, but I'd like to avoid javascript code for this

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever manage to solve this?